# wrong calculation of power query - 101

Tags: sum, pivot

my data in the table is

```
2.8202148
1.810577904
4.399182566
78.56037454
4.62585733
3.905997503
3.877795355
```

normal sum gives the result as `99.9999999954482`

but in pivot table (power query) it gives 101 ! somehow...

any suggestions ?

Thanks,

Comment: `101` is the sum of the 7 numbers you gave where each number is first _rounded_ to an integer (and check this yourself).  You need to change the precision of the power query.

Comment: Data Type : Decimal Number

Decimal Number – Represents a 64 bit (eight-byte) floating point number. It’s the most common number type and corresponds to numbers as you usually think of them.  Although designed to handle numbers with fractional values, it also handles whole numbers.  The Decimal Number type can handle negative values from -1.79E +308 through -2.23E -308, 0, and positive values from 2.23E -308 through 1.79E + 308. For example, numbers like 34, 34.01, and 34.000367063 are valid decimal numbers. The largest value that can be represented in a Decimal Number type is 15 digits long.

Answer (score 0):

If I round those numbers to their nearest integer, and then sum then, I get 101. You've probably set up something to use integers instead of floating point numbers. Change to to floating point and you should be fine.

Comment: Concurrent; the time shows my answer was 1 minute before your comment.